# Unable to center text with CSS + HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my text with CSS and HTML. I'm really new to web development and so am just getting started. I watched a course on the basics (made the first page) and now I'm working on my own project (the other pages)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* font-size: 10px; */
  font-size: 62.5%
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.second-page {
  background-color: #04041af9;
  padding: 4.8rem 0 9.6rem 0;
}

.our-news {
  max-width: 130rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 9.6rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading-secondary {
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  /*line-height: 1.05;*/
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="second-page">
  <div class="our-news">
    <h1 class="heading-secondary">
      Why buy through us?
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

However, it simply will not center! I've spent hours researching it so I've finally come here for help. I've attached an image of what it looks like:

[image: The problem]

All I want is for it to appear central) - horizontally at least!
How am I supposed to achieve this (note that the section is the second)? Thanks.

Comment: You set a grid with 2 columns and your h1 stay on the first column (and here it is centered) just add to h1 grid-column: 1 / span 2;

Answer (score 0):

1. You have uneven padding in your `section`. You need to provide uniform values like `padding: 5rem 0;` so that the spacing is even in the entire section
2. You have used `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` in `.our-news`  which tells that there will be 2 columns inside the container which occupies equal space. So you need to change this line to:

   `grid-template-columns: 1fr;`
3. You gave a margin bottom to `heading-secondary`. Remove that line so that there won't be any unwanted spaces below the text.

Modified code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* font-size: 10px; */
  font-size: 62.5%
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.second-page {
  background-color: #04041af9;
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.our-news {
  max-width: 130rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 9.6rem;
  align-items: center;

}

.heading-secondary {
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  /*line-height: 1.05;*/
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="second-page">
      <div class="our-news">
        <h1 class="heading-secondary">
          Why buy through us?
        </h1>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it very simple with `text-align: center`. Without flex or grid.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* font-size: 10px; */
  font-size: 62.5%
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.second-page {
  background-color: #04041af9;
  padding: 4.8rem 0 9.6rem 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.our-news {
  text-align: center; /* only this one you need!*/
}

.heading-secondary {
  font-size: 5.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
  width: 360px;
  display: inline-block; /* make the block element to a inliner*/
  
}
```

```html
<section class="second-page">
  <div class="our-news">
    <h1 class="heading-secondary">
      Why buy through us?
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But OP must remove display:grid from .our-news

Comment: @Sfili_81 Have I got it wrong? But I still see that `our-news` is still display: grid.

Comment: The OP has set display grid with 2 columns in the our-news div. You removed it as i can see.... [ your answer is correct my point is to advise OP to remove display:grid ;)]

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thank you for pointing out. Yes indeed, my suggestion was to the OP to remove the grid and work with simple text-align. Grid is for this case not needed. Merci and have a nice day :-)